# Dimension about space of matrices of order 3 over the field of the real.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Consider the vector space of the matrices of order 3 over the field of the real $M_{3}\left(\Re\right)$ numbers. and let S be the subspace such that is spanned by the matrices of the form $AB-BA$. What is the dimension of S?

I was thinking in... the form of that matrix, and i know... If $X=AB−BA$ , then $trX=tr(AB−BA)=tr(AB)−tr(BA)=tr(AB)−tr(AB)=0$

well, i worked in an basis of that space... this:

$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\} $,

it's fine the basis?

Comment: It seems unlikely that you have no ideas about tackling this problem.  Find some examples of matrices of the form $AB-BA$ (the technical term is "commutator").  Check a bunch of these for linear independence.  Add your observations to the Question as "context".

Comment: I think in the inverse matrix, because she's linearly independent, no? @hardmath

Comment: The question was about the dimension of $S$.  This has little (or nothing) to do with a matrix inverse.  Check the definition of dimension of a vector space.

Comment: I was thinking in... the form of that matrix, and i know... If $X=AB−BA$, then
$trX=tr(AB−BA)=tr(AB)−tr(BA)=tr(AB)−tr(AB)=0$.

Comment: That's the basis of matrices with trace 0, but can all matrices with trace 0 can be expressed as $AB-BA$?

Comment: yep, for that: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conmutador_de_dos_operadores @PeterShor

Comment: It looks to me like you've found all the pieces you need to answer this.  Do you want to post your own answer to this Question?

Comment: Yes! @hardmath how i can answe my question?

Comment: Look for a button toward the bottom of the page about adding an Answer.  (It may ask if you are sure you really mean to Answer your own Question, rather than editing the Question, but in this case you do.  I can help with formatting, if needed.)

Comment: @hardmath can you review the answer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X=AB-BA$ then $tr(X)=tr(AB-BA) = tr(AB) - tr(BA) = 0 $ we have the subspace of matrices with trace = 0, and I found the basis for the space:

$\left\{ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\\ \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1
\end{pmatrix},\right\} 
 $

then the dimension of the space is 8.

Comment: Note that we can be sure of this dimension because the entire space of $3\times 3$ matrics has dimension $9$, and $S$ is a proper subspace because not all $3\times 3$ matrices have zero trace.